# Solve trigonometric expression

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry, variable

Mathematica is not able to solve this expression :

$Solve[ 2 e ==  h + r * sin[theta  - q ] + b* sin [theta ] + e*cos[theta ] , theta]$

Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

Could you help me ? I would like an expression $theta = ....$ 
Even replacing the other variables with numbers doenst help, and I am sure this expression as a solution.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
expr = 2 e == h + r Sin[theta \[Minus] q] + b Sin[theta] + e Cos[theta];
expr // TrigExpand // Solve[#, theta] & // theta /. (First @#  /. C[1] -> 0) &
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]